# Selecting a drop down list element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

A drop down list appears on mouse over on a link, so there is no need to click to open a dropdown list.

```html
<ul id="XenForoUniq4">
  <li class="PrefixGroup">
    <h3>some header</h3>
    <ul>
      <li class="PrefixOption"><a href="javascript:">option 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="PrefixOption"><a href="javascript:">option 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="PrefixOption selected">
    <a href="javascript:" class="prefix noPrefix">no option selected</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How to select one of the elements in such case?

Answer (score 0):

There is an `Actions` class in Selenium that exposes a `MoveToElement()` method that allows you to hover the link in order to make visible the list.